# windows equivalent of linux ssh -X server command

Tags: windows, ssh, gnome

I have a linux server, and from my linux client I run a graphical app on the server issuing on the client

> ssh -X server command

command is a gnome app

Is there a way to do the same from a windows client?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you can make use of X-forwarding by combining the [Xming X server](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) and the [PuTTY terminal](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Finding the download link for Xming on their website isn't easy, so here are the direct download links:

- [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming/6.9.0.31/Xming-6-9-0-31-setup.exe/download)
- [PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe)

PuTTY doesn't require installation, just running the executable starts the program.

You can find instructions on how to enable X forwarding on the internet, such as in [this blog post](http://blog.nth-design.com/2010/05/19/x11-putty-xming/).

Basically, all you need to do is go down to Connection, then SSH and then X11, and check the box for X forwarding. This is the equivalent of using `ssh -X` on the command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install XMing on your Windows (or any X-Server for windows).